# How to convert JavaScript to PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone help me convert this to PHP?

```
var encoded = '';
var resnumber = 0;

for (v = 1; v <= evnumber; v++) {
    var indcode = v + 'code';
    var valcode = document.getElementById(indcode).value;

    valcode = valcode.trim();

    var indname = v + 'name';
    var valname = document.getElementById(indname).value;
    valname = valname.trim();
    var indleague = v + 'league';
    var valleague = document.getElementById(indleague).value;
    valleague = valleague.trim();

    var inddate = v + 'date';
    var valdate = document.getElementById(inddate).value;

    valdate = valdate.trim();
    var indtime = v + 'time';
    var valtime = document.getElementById(indtime).value;
    valtime = valtime.trim();
    var indnumb = v + 'numb';
    var valnumb = document.getElementById(indnumb).value;
    valnumb = valnumb.trim();
    valnumb = parseInt(valnumb);
    encoded = encoded + valcode + '<e>' + valname + '<e>' + valleague + '<e>' + valdate + '<e>' + valtime + '<e>' + valnumb + '<e>';
    for (w = 0; w < valnumb; w++) {
        var indtype = v + 'signe|' + w;
        var valtype = document.getElementById(indtype).value;
        valtype = valtype.trim();
        var indodd = v + 'odd|' + w;
        var valodd = document.getElementById(indodd).value;

        valodd = valodd.trim();
        encoded = encoded + valtype + '<e>' + valodd + '<e>';
        resnumber++;
    }

    encoded = encoded + '|';
}


encoded = encoded + '<results>';

for (t = 0; t < resnumber; t++) {
    encoded = encoded + '<res>';
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack isn't a free code conversion service.

Comment: javascript runs on the client (browser). PHP runs on the server. they are not well suited to replace each other's functionality.

Comment: Downvote for obvious "please do my homework for me".

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply convert this to PHP because it's dealing with values from DOM elements. The syntax between PHP and Javascript is very similar, from the list of your examples I can show you their counterparts:

```
var encoded = '';
$encoded = '';

var resnumber = 0;
$resnumber = 0;

for(v=1;v<=evnumber;v++) {
for( $v=1; $v<=$evnumber; $v++ ) {

var indcode = v + 'code';
$indcode = $v + 'code';

var valcode = document.getElementById(indcode).value;
// This is an example of something you can't do with PHP, because it doesnt have access to the document unless your parsing it with DOMDocument or something.
```